# c# serial communication: manipulating received data

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am receiving data serially from a microcontroller on my c# app. I am using the following simple code:

```
private void comPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e){
    RxString = comPort.ReadExisting();
    this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText));
}

private void DisplayText(object sender, EventArgs e){
    richTextBox1.AppendText(RxString);
}
```

I am receiving exactly what I am sending from the microcontroller but the problem is that I am not able to modify the received string. (eg I was trying to do
`char[] externalModeMsg_array = RxString.ToCharArray();`) But no success :(

Can anybody tell me that what mistake I am doing.Should I read in a different way and how to manipulate the received string (RxString).

Comment: It would probably be best get rid of `DisplayText` and just put that code into `comPort_DataReceived`. That way you don't need the global variable, `RxString`. Also, why doesn't `char[] externalModeMsg_array = RxString.ToCharArray();` not work?

Comment: Where, what, and how are you trying to modify RxString? Where, what, and how is RxString declared? Is it const? Is comPort_DataReceived running on a thread? We'll get to your usage of ReadExisting after we get some more info.

Answer (score 0):

```
richTextBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => richTextBox1.AppendText = RxString);
```

This may be of some use to you.

Best,
Paul